# Driver install fails on Epson Xp-620

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on both of my laptops - a 6 yr old Acer and an 18 mo old Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series. I did the Acer first and the 'add printer' handily found and configured my Epson XP-620 printer. Test page looked good!

After the Dell machine was configured with the same Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (both derived from the same bootable stick) I tried to add the same Epson printer. During the 'espcr' driver install the progress bar permanently froze after some 20 seconds. I've tried it several times trying both the DNS and pass thru options. Neither does the trick. I also notice that in the list of printer makes and models the Epson XP-620 is missing. That didn't seem to matter with the success on the Acer. There seems to be no communication problem, evidenced by the fact that if I choose another Epson model the printer simply shoots blanks.

What can I do?

Comment: How did you install the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Epson supply the driver from [here](https://epson.com/Support/Printers/All-In-Ones/XP-Series/Epson-XP-620/s/SPT_C11CE01201?review-filter=Linux)

if you click ACCEPT and then select the 64bit deb file (assuming you are using 64bit ubuntu) epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.20-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

installing that should trigger the system to register the printer and allow you to print

Comment: I have downloaded the driver. Being new to Linux I don't know how to install it apart from using the 'add printer' utility. Perhaps you mean from the Terminal. Could you be more specific on how I should install it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry; if you use the Dash search box; and look for the folder that is called Downloads; if you double-click to open Downloads; inside it should be that package you downloaded; if you then double-click on that; (or right-click and select INSTALL): then that should install the drivers; that should trigger a registration of the printer for you; open LibreOFfice; the writing programme and type a few words; select print and see if you have a new XP-830 option; if not, look for the PRINTERS folder; if you open that, it has a NEW button; to register a new printer; click that and it should do things

Comment: well done; enjoy